# Question about using Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability

Suppose I have the following, with X having some probability mass function

$P(X=i | X\ge 1)=\frac{P(X=i,i \ge 1)}{P(X\ge 1)},i=1,2,...,n$

How might I solve this? I was considering that since "i" starts at 1 then the denominator is always true so the probability of  $P(X\ge 1)=1$

and things simplify to

$P(X=i | X\ge 1)=P(X=i,i \ge 1),i=1,2,...,n$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X=i) $

Would this be appropriate?

Comment: You know anything about $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. $$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X=i\mid X\geq 1) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=i\land X\geq 1)}{\mathsf P(X\geq i)} \\[1ex] &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=i)~\mathbf 1_{i\geq 1}}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathsf P(X = k)}\end{split}$$

Where the indicator function, $\mathbf 1_{i\geq 1}$, equals $1$ when $i\geq 1$, otherwise it equals $0$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X=i,\,i\geq 1)=\begin{cases}P(X=1) & \text{if } i=1,\cr 
P(X=2) & \text{if } i=2, \cr
\ldots \cr
P(X=n) & \text{if } i=n \end{cases}$$
$$P(X\geq 1)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(X=i).$$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have such a random variable. From the given equation and definition of conditional probabilities we have $P(X=i)=P(X=j, j \geq 1)$ whenever $i \geq 1$ but this is possible only when $P(X=i)=0$ for all $i \geq 0$. But then $P(X=j, j \geq 1)=0$ or $P(X\geq 1)=0$. In this case the conditional probabilities in the statement are nor even defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, for instance, consider the following case:

If I throw a coin and get Heads, then $X=1$, otherwise $X=0$.
So, 
$$P(X=1 | X \geq 1) = \frac{P(X=1 \cap X\geq 1)}{P(X \geq 1)}$$
$$= \frac{1/2}{1/2}$$
$$= 1$$
$$\neq P(X = 1)$$